# React Hooks State update one step behind. For this reason my changes are not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to see the changes in the use of react hooks on state immediately. My changes are one step behind on state. How can I solve this.

```
const [categoryID, setCategoryID] = useState(0);

const changeCategory = (e) => {
    setCategoryID(e.target.value);
    console.log(categoryID);
  };

<Field
     as="select"
     onChange={changeCategory}
     style={formStyle().inputStyle}
     className="form-control"
     type="text"
     name="categoryID"
      >
```

When I select the first value, the result appears 0. If I chose my second value, I see the value I chose first on the console.

Comment: So `categoryID` will be updated on the next render. You already know what value it will be updated to, so while you wait for it, you can log `console.log(e.target.value)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State change is asynchronous in react hooks hence there is no guarantee that the state will be updated just after setting it.
For this reason we have `useEffect` to the rescue that accepts a dependency and will be executed after that dependency is changed.

Example-

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(categoryID);
},[categoryID])
```

Now in this case the dependency is `categoryID` and whenever it's value is changed the function will be executed and will console the updated value.

Comment: I want to do multiple operations like this. I have another select element and I want to keep the data on it as well. What should I do in this situation. As far as I know useEffect takes a single array

Comment: @Gucal I didn't understand your query but if you want you can have as many useEffects as you want. You can also pass multiple dependcies like [categoryID, searchString]. In this way whenever any of the dependcies value is changed useEffects function will be called.

Comment: Hi! [ ] what is the difference between this usage and [1] this usage?

Comment: @Gucal In this case whenever the categoryId will be changed the useEffect will be called whereas in case of `[1]` the useEffect will be called only one time after component mounts.

Comment: Why does it update with categoryID when I leave it blank?

Answer (score 2):

The main reason behind this behavior is `setState` is **asynchronous** so the changes should not be expected immediately.

Specially for this cases there is a hook called `useEffect()` to capture changes on state. If you add `categoryId` into the dependency array of `useEffect` then it will be trigger once you have change on that state. Thus you can log your changes as the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('changed', categoryID);
}, [categoryID]);
```

Suggested read is [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: This seems like an extreme measure to capture data that is already available at the point where OP needs it.

Comment: @spender Just mentioned for the sake of example but of course the `e.target.value` can be logged in that place for sure.

Comment: @spender how do i keep it global that way?

Comment: I want to do multiple operations like this. I have another select element and I want to keep the data on it as well. What should I do in this situation. As far as I know useEffect takes a single array. @norbitrial