# useState variable is one step behind its assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry in advance if the question is a bit vague, still quite new to JS and react. Anyways, my problem is that in the following code the newFilter state hook is one step behind the event.target.value, which should have been assigned to newFilter at onChange, could anyone enlighten me why the newFilter gets updated one step later?

Output in console from console.log, when input change happens:

[image]

The code:

```
function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [newFilter, setNewFilter] = useState('');
  const [allCountries, setAllCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all").then((response) => {
      setAllCountries(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {

    setNewFilter(event.target.value);
    console.log("this is event.target.value", event.target.value)
    console.log("this is the newFilter", newFilter)

    if (event.target.value) {
      let countriesToShow = allCountries.filter((country) =>
      country.name.common.toLowerCase().match(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
      );
      setCountries(countriesToShow);
    }

  };

  return (
    <div>
        <strong>
          <p>Find countries</p>
        </strong>{" "}
        <input value={newFilter} onChange={handleFilterChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: did u try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885737/react-hooks-state-update-one-step-behind-for-this-reason-my-changes-are-not-wor

Comment: because `setNewFilter` is asyncronous. when you update the state the component is rerendered with the new state

Answer (score 1):

React state updates are asynchronous & are not run immediately (kind of like `setTimeout(func , 0)`.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous.

Hence when you update a state property using its previous value, you should use the callback argument for the state setter.

```
handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    this.setState((state)=> {
        newFilter: event.target.value,
        countries: (event.target.value)?allCountries.filter(...):allCountries   
    });
}
```